# Is there a way to use setInterval with preact signals in order to render a component?

Tags: reactjs, preact

I would like to achieve this behavior using signals:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('This will run every second!');
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

Do I need to compute first and then use effect according to their documentation? source: https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/signals/

Any tip will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use compute here, you can go ahead and use effect. Count signal will be updated everytime interval fires.

```
import { signal, effect } from "@preact/signals";

const count = signal(0);

function Counter() {
  effect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      count.value ++;
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  });

  return <div>{count}</div>;
}
```

Comment: let slideInterval;
effect(()=>{
            slideInterval = setInterval(()=>{
                console.log("interval started");
                if (count.value === slideLength-1) {
                    return count.value = 0
                }
                else {
                    console.log("add one to count", count.value++);
                    return count.value++;
                };
            }, intervalTime);
        return () => clearInterval(slideInterval);
    });
```
This is counting +2 instead of +1, do you perhaps know what could be the reason?

Comment: It is kind of similar to what you shared above, however, for some reason it is adding +2, and it doesn't get into into the first condition, jumps straight to the else condition all the time.

Comment: You've written `count.value++` twice, that will add +2 of course.

Comment: as @rschristian explained, you have count.value++ twice